# How To Read the TextBox value which is dynamically added into gridview on ajax tab container

Tags: ajax, vb.net, gridview

I'm facing difficult condition to read the value from text box which is dynamically added into gridview which is inside TabPanel of AjaxTabContainer.

Note, all controls are added dynamically as per user options.

The sequence would be as follow:

```
  
Design Time:
One Panel and other user options (date & some other fields)

Run Time:
- Add AjaxTab container & Tab Panel which is vary upon user filter (Tab created based on db -records)
- Inside each tab, added the GridView with dataset
- Add some textbox into each of GridView Line
```

On Page: 
I can successfully show tab control with gridview with text box (*as below)[image: Dynamic TextBox]
Now, how to read value inside each text box when user click 'Update' button? 
I try to use FindControls, but nothing.

My code:-

```
Private Sub DynamicTabGVLoad(ByVal seqno As String)
        createTab()
        ds = allotmentdb.getRoomType()
        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim tabcontent As New Control()
            Dim tbldynamic As New Table()
            Dim tbrdynamic As New TableRow()
            Dim tbcdynamic As New TableCell()           
            Dim roomtypekey As String
            roomtypekey = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("roomtypekey").ToString()
            Dim gv_alines As New GridView
            gv_alines.AutoGenerateColumns = True
            gv_alines.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            Dim ds1 As New Data.DataSet()
            ds1 = allotmentdb.getAllotmentLinesTabGV(roomtypekey, seqno, System.DateTime.Now.ToString(("yyyy-MM-dd")))
            gv_alines.EmptyDataText = "No Record Found!"
            'gv_alines.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = True
            gv_alines.DataSource = ds1
            gv_alines.DataBind()
            If gv_alines.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                gv_alines.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Visible = False
                gv_alines.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Visible = False
                gv_alines.HeaderRow.Cells(4).Visible = False
                For Each gvr As GridViewRow In gv_alines.Rows
                    gvr.Cells(0).Visible = False
                    gvr.Cells(1).Visible = False
                    gvr.Cells(4).Visible = False
                    Dim txtInternetRoom As New TextBox()
                    txtInternetRoom.ID = "txtInternetRoom"
                    txtInternetRoom.Text = gvr.Cells(5).Text
                    txtInternetRoom.Style.Add("text-align", "right")
                    txtInternetRoom.Width = 100
                    gvr.Cells(5).Controls.Add(txtInternetRoom)
                    Dim txtInternetRate As New TextBox()
                    txtInternetRate.ID = "txtInternetRate"
                    txtInternetRate.Text = FormatNumber(gvr.Cells(6).Text, 2)
                    If txtInternetRate.Text = "0.00" Then txtInternetRate.Text = "NA"
                    txtInternetRate.Style.Add("text-align", "right")
                    txtInternetRate.Width = 100
                    gvr.Cells(6).Controls.Add(txtInternetRate)
                    Dim txtInternetRate2 As New TextBox()
                    txtInternetRate2.ID = "txtInternetRate2"
                    txtInternetRate2.Text = FormatNumber(gvr.Cells(7).Text)
                    If txtInternetRate2.Text = "0.00" Then txtInternetRate2.Text = "NA"
                    txtInternetRate2.Style.Add("text-align", "right")
                    txtInternetRate2.Width = 100
                    gvr.Cells(7).Controls.Add(txtInternetRate2)
                    Dim txtInternetRate3 As New TextBox()
                    txtInternetRate3.ID = "txtInternetRate3"
                    txtInternetRate3.Text = FormatNumber(gvr.Cells(8).Text)
                    If txtInternetRate3.Text = "0.00" Then txtInternetRate3.Text = "NA"
                    txtInternetRate3.Style.Add("text-align", "right")
                    txtInternetRate3.Width = 100
                    gvr.Cells(8).Controls.Add(txtInternetRate3)
                    Dim txtInternetRate4 As New TextBox()
                    txtInternetRate4.ID = "txtInternetRate4"
                    txtInternetRate4.Text = FormatNumber(gvr.Cells(9).Text)
                    If txtInternetRate4.Text = "0.00" Then txtInternetRate4.Text = "NA"
                    txtInternetRate4.Style.Add("text-align", "right")
                    txtInternetRate4.Width = 100
                    gvr.Cells(9).Controls.Add(txtInternetRate4)
                Next
            Else               
            End If
            tbcdynamic.Controls.Add(gv_alines)
            tbrdynamic.Cells.Add(tbcdynamic)
            tbldynamic.Rows.Add(tbrdynamic)
            tabcontent.Controls.Add(tbldynamic)
            ajxTab.Tabs(i).Controls.Add(tabcontent)
        Next
        pnlDynamic.Controls.Add(ajxTab)
    End Sub
    Private Sub createTab()
        ds = allotmentdb.getRoomType()
        ajxTab = New AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer()
        ajxTab.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
        'Me.Controls.Add(ajxTab)
        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            Dim tbpnlDynamic As New TabPanel()
            tbpnlDynamic.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            tbpnlDynamic.HeaderText = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("RoomType").ToString()
            tbpnlDynamic.ID = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("RoomTypeKey").ToString()
            tbpnlDynamic.Visible = True
            ajxTab.Tabs.Add(tbpnlDynamic)
            ajxTab.ActiveTabIndex = 0
        Next
    End Sub
```

I need it very **urgently**. Thanks in advance!